# Direct Kafka Stream with PySpark (Apache Spark 1.6)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I'm trying to leverage the direct kafka consumer (new feature available in python), to capture data from a custom Kafka Producer that I'm running on localhost:9092.

I'm currently using the "direct_kafka_wordcount.py" as provided by the spark 1.6 example scripts.

**Source**: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/direct_kafka_wordcount.py

**DOCS**:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html

I'm using the following command the run the program:

```
    ~/spark-1.6.0/bin/spark-submit --jars 
    ~/spark-1.6.0/external/kafka-assembly/target/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.0.jar           
direct_kafka_wordcount.py localhost:9092 twitter.live
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a strange error, which I'm not able to debug. Any tips/suggestions will be immensely appreciated.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
        at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper.createDirectStreamWithoutMessageHandler(KafkaUtils.scala:688)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

means the `topic` does not exist, or the brokers are not reachable or there is some network(proxy) kind of issue.

Make sure there is no such connectivity issue by running `kafka-console-consumer` on the spark master & worker nodes.

Comment: I get the same issue as @cynical biscuit , and I'm sure the topic is existed and master and slave node could access the topic. However, I'm still getting the same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Decula: It can also come if the hostname of brokers are not configured in your driver & slaves. When you contact zookeeper for offset range to read, it actually uses the hostname of the kafka brokers (I faced this on EMR). This should be printed in the logs somewhere. Look out for those broker names and check if the driver/slave machine can resolve it or not ! If not, add the hostname-IP mapping in /etc/hosts file

Comment: This worked for me. My problem was I was using the wrong port.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. But turn out to be different solution. I had different versions of scala running for spark and kafka.

I ended up using same version on both side then pyspark was able to generate the classes.

I used following

Spark: `spark-1.6.3-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`
spark-streaming-kafka: `spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.3.jar`

Answer (score 0):

In my case in spark streaming which consumer topic from kafka:

Get error as this and programs exit.
So I check `metadata.broker.list`, only one of the brokers was added.
Adding all the brokers other then one of them.
And every goes well，but still get warn `org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException` ,so I check kafka brokers status from zk and find the one broker was brokedown which casue such error.